# Invalid request when posting Youtube video to Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, youtube

I have this code which i am using to schedule posts to Facebook using the Graph api:

```
$body = array(
   'message'         => $post->message,
   'link'            => site_url('index.php/cron/redirect/'.url_encode($post->id_cron)),
   'picture'         => 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$post->picture.'/0.jpg',
   'name'            => $post->name,
   'caption'         => $post->caption,
   'description'     => $post->description,
   'access_token'    => $access_token, 
   'appsecret_proof' => hash_hmac('sha256', $access_token, $this->faceboook->app_secret),
   'type'        => 'video',
   'source'          => 'http://www.youtube.com/e/'.$post->picture
);
$relative_url = "/".$post->id_wall."/feed";

$batch = array('method' => 'POST', 'relative_url' => $relative_url, 'body' => http_build_query($body));

$facebook->api('?batch='.urlencode(json_encode($batch)), 'POST');
```

Now the post is successfully being posted on the wall of the group, the links are right, the thumbnail is correct and it is being displayed as a video since the little play button is shown on the lower left of the thumbnail. Now the problem is I get

```
"Invalid Error: There was a problem with the parameters of the request"
```

whenever i try to click the thumbnail. Where the expected action is that the post will open a player and play the video on the group wall. What seems to be the problem here? Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you replace your link with YouTube video URL
'link' =>"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + [YoutubeId]; and see the videos now showing or not.

Normally to share YouTube videos to Facebook pages you only need message, link, source, 
picture parameters. Thats is if you are using FacebookC#SDK to share video to Facebook all you need is following code

```
 var fb = new Facebook.FacebookClient(yourPageAccessToken); 
 argList["message"] = message;
 argList["link"] = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + specialOffer.YoutubeId;
 argList["source"] = "http://www.youtube.com/v/" + specialOffer.YoutubeId;
 argList["picture"] = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + specialOffer.YoutubeId + "/0.jpg";
 fb.Post("feed", argList);
```